# Eclipse not recognizing EAR when doing m2e import

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using Eclipse Kepler, when I import an EAR pom it imports the project but does not include the ear facet. I have to click create facet project and select the EAR facet manually. Is there a way I can get m2e to import it as an actual EAR project?